# Right nav/ad panel overlapping comments

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

Using "Full site", Chrome (latest), iPhone 6S, iOS10.0.2.

The right side of question's comments are extending under the panel right panel.

Comments to *answers* seem to be OK though.

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That's the full site view, not the mobile view (so, the [meta-tag:mobile-web] isn't right). If on a mobile phone, you really should use the mobile theme.

Comment: @Oded OK - Q amended. There are lots of functions not available on the mobile app or mobile version. It's unusable to me, so I never use it.

Comment: I do agree with you, but since mobile browsers [aren't supported in full site view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/307988) this is pretty much `status-bydesign` right?

Comment: The desktop site (full site) is designed for desktop displays. Given the mobile view exists for mobile phones specifically, we will not be working on making the desktop view work on mobiles. Declining.